# Detect User Interaction with embedded Facebook post

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've got several Facebook posts embedded on a page using the Javascript SDK. What I would like to know is if there is a way for me to detect when a user interacts with one of the posts (e.g. likes it, shares it, etc). I know you can subscribe to events in the API, I don't see anything in [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.5) about subscribing to events from an embedded post. Maybe I'm not looking in the right place.

I want to do something like the following:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('like.create', callback)
```

Comment: Why do you want to know that?

Comment: For analytics. To see if a user interacts with the content on my page. I don't care about tracking their Facebook ID or really even what action they took. I'm only interested in seeing if they interacted with the post somehow.